# runtime error when using pointer of map

Tags: c++

How to use pointer to access map element? I searched and got this which gets runtime error:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
map<string, int> *myFruit;
int main()
{
    (*myFruit)["apple"] = 1;
}
```

what is the right way for this? I searched but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: You did not allocate `myFruit`.

Comment: Please help, if there is already an answer give their links instead of downvoting.

Comment: sorry I am beginner in c++. What does allocate mean?

Comment: I assume people downvoted because this is too simple of a problem to help anyone in the future. StackOverflow is about asking good questions with good answers that can help people in the future with the same problem.

Comment: Why are you using pointers here at all? I wouldn't use pointers with this code.

Comment: I reduced the error portion of my another code, then posted here. I need pointer for the original one.

Comment: @agassaa _"I need pointer for the original one."_ I'm pretty sure you don't.

Comment: wait I don't get you. Are you telling me to put the original code here? okay here it is, please help if it can be done without pointer: http://ideone.com/VndeVr

Comment: You certainly don't need a pointer with `myFruit` in the linked code. Also you repeat the same mistake with your other pointers.

Comment: @agassaa What you linked is completely silly stuff you don't need a single pointer or array of pointers (which is your actual culprit because it's not initialized) there.

Comment: Actually in my original code, I needed to work with another map element in dfs function. So, to avoid creating a new one I wanted to work with the pointer, which reduces time complexity.

Comment: @agassaa Use a reference then. If you're really sure you need a pointer rather use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ please provide an example of using reference for map. I am new on this.

Comment: @agassaa An answerer already did.

Comment: My advice is to read a book on `c++` programming instead of trying to learn by random examples on the web. Your code shows you lack some very basic c++ knowledge.

Comment: @drescherjm Wouldn't call this particulary basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `map<string, int> *myFruit;` myFruit is a pointer to a map. But ask yourself what instance of a map does it point to? The answer is: none. It hasn't been set to point to any instance. You haven't initialized it at all. And your example program never creates any instance of a map anywhere either!

So with that said, it should be no surprise that trying to use myFruit will then cause problems.

Remember there is a difference between the pointer and what it points to. If this is unclear, then find some good educational materials on C++ and read them.

---

In this example we could solve the problem by creating (aka allocating) an instance for the pointer to point to. Such as `map<string, int> *myFruit = new map<string, int>();` Of course one should remember to properly `delete` that instance later.

Although as other comments have touched on, in such a simple example it seems silly even use a pointer like that. It would be easier to just create an instance directly, such as `map<string, int> myFruit;`

Now if you're actually trying to do something like pass a map to a function, then you might have a reason to pass by pointer, such as `void SomeFunction(map<string, int> *parameter)`. But as comments have mentioned, that might be done more gracefully via a reference, such as `void SomeFunction(map<string, int> &parameter)`.

But if you're trying to do something else that you really think you need a pointer for, and if you're not able to make it work right, then perhaps you should ask a question with more context about what you're actually trying to do and why.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid pointers where possible, especially for simple tasks. Prefer programming with values.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> myFruit;
    myFruit["apple"] = 1;
}
```

Besides avoiding pointers, there is something else that is worth mentioning. Your example defines `myFruit` as a global variable. Pointers are error prone, global variables are dangerous, put them together and you will likely get into trouble sooner or later. Since `main` kicks off your program, you can pass myFruit to the functions that will use it allowing the scope of the variable to be dramatically reduced and thereby making the code much easier to understand.

From reading the code linked in one of the comments, I believe there are many ways you can improve you code in general.

1. Functions should take all of the data they operate on as parameters. This removes any need for globals and the only exceptions should be extreme edge cases.
2. Try to name your functions appropriately, `getsz` is a poor name, `get_size` would be better but it is still misleading because the function doesn't return a value, it actually mutates a global. No one would expect a getter to *observably* mutate a global variable.
3. Ideally, the method would have a signature like

   ```
   int calculate_size(int vertexIndex, int parentVertexIndex, const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vertices);
   ```

Comment: `#include <string>` and `std::string`.

Comment: I'd say you should avoid fancy `auto` tricks when explaining something to a novice.

Comment: What is fancy to you now will be run of the mill in the future. C++ relies heavily on type inference and this trend continues to increase.